# Am I allowed to join the The Sphinx's Lair?

Tags: support, chat

Am I allowed to join the *The Sphinx's Lair*?
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair
The link keeps asking me to wait "Just a second..."

Answer (score 5):

You should be allowed to join - there's no mechanic that bars people from entry like that. It sounds like there's some sort of internet connection issue. (Maybe a firewall?)

Answer (score 4):

This problem have been acknowledged in these Meta Stack Exchange posts:

[chat room constantly re-loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163990/773001)

[Chat hanging during load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95444/773001)

[I'm unable to join chat in Safari on my iPhone when on my mobile network (O2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120356/773001)

[Chat channel keeps loading forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161632/773001)

You'll probably have more luck searching for these generic kinds of question in the main meta site.